# Break a string into list of list of integers

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, integer

I have this code:

```
content = [line.rstrip('\r\n') for line in open('Ch02/digits/testDigits/0_0.txt')]
content = [[x] for x in content]
content[0][0]
```

and I get this output:

```
'00000000000001100000000000000000'
```

Say I wanted to convert this string into a list of integers like:
[[0],[0],....,[0]], what's the pythonic solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
s = '001100'

list_of_lists = [[int(ch)] for ch in s]

>> [[0], [0], [1], [1], [0], [0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
content = [line.rstrip('\r\n') for line in open('Ch02/digits/testDigits/0_0.txt')]
lst = []
for each in content:
    lst.append([[x] for x in each])
lst = np.array(lst)
lst.reshape(32,32)
```